# Replace string in form that is using GET (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to modify a string that I am sending using the GET function in PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<form action= "lookup.php" method = "get">
  <div class="input-group">

    <!--Enter Name with # afterwards-->
    <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <select name="region" class="form-control" style="width: 80px">
        <option value = "us">United States</option>
        <option value = "eu">Europe</option>
        <option value = "cn">China</option>
        <option value = "kr">Korea</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-royal"></button>
    </span>
  </div>    
</form>
```

Basically what happens is the user will type in their name and a number, for example **John#1**, making the URL:

> lookup.php?name=John%231&region=us

But I want to turn the # sign into a dash, so the URL becomes:

> lookup.php?name=John-1&region=us

How can I do this? Is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: you could use javascript to "add an event listener" on the "submit" event of the form to "replace" the '#' by a '-' of the element "name" value.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the **#** values as the user enters the input. Just add an `oninput` callback function and replace **#** with **-**. An example is given below using JQuery.

```
<input type ="text" oninput="replaceHash()" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"/>

<script>
function replaceHash(){
    var name=$('#name').val();
    name=name.replace("#","-");
    $('#name').val(name);
}
</script>
```

(I have used JQuery instead of pure JavaScript. You can easily do the same using pure JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is perfectly fine to do this, but I think it would be better to replace those # characters on submit (`onsubmit` callback), because it's less confusing for the users that way. (That's just how i would do it though)

Answer (score 0):

You can do either replacing the `#` after request received -- by PHP

```
$name = urldecode($_GET['name']);
$name = str_replace('#', '-', $php);
```

Or, before request is sent -- by JavaScript

Assuming your form will have name attribute: "myform". `<form name="myform" action="lookup.php" method="get">` (you can change any selector suitable for you). And then listen on `onsubmit` event

```
document.myform.onsubmit = function() {
    var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
    var replace = name.value.replace('#', '-');
    name.value = replace;
}
```

or one with jQuery

```
$('form[name="myform"]').on('submit', function(){
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var replace = name.replace('#', '-');
    $('input[name="name"]').val(replace);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>frmexample</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function Redirect() {
                var  frm_name=$("#frm_name").val();
                frm_name=frm_name.replace("#","-");
                var region=$("#region").val();
                var url="lookup.php?name="+frm_name+"&region="+region;
               window.location=url;
            }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="sub_frm"  method = "get">
  <div class="input-group">

    <!--Enter Name with # afterwards-->
    <input type ="text" class="form-control" id="frm_name" name="name"/>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <select name="region" id="region" class="form-control" style="width: 80px">
        <option value = "us">United States</option>
        <option value = "eu">Europe</option>
        <option value = "cn">China</option>
        <option value = "kr">Korea</option>
      </select>
    </span>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-royal" onclick="Redirect();">submit</button>
    </span>
  </div>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks.